# What is the advantages of using generator expression in CMake?

Tags: cmake, expression

Recently, I learned how to use the generator expression in CMake to do the conditional linking and conditional definitions.

However, in my opinion, I can also use the flow control syntax in CMake to do the same thing. I do not know what the advantages of the generator expression in CMake are. For example, I can use the following generator expression syntax.

```
$<STREQUAL:string1,string2> 
$<EQUAL:number1,number2> 
$<VERSION_EQUAL:version1,version2> 
$<VERSION_GREATER:version1,version2> 
$<VERSION_LESS:version1,version2>
```

But I can also use the `if() elseif() endif()` to get the same goal. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using *generator expressions* one can configure the project differently for different build types in multi-configuration [generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generators.7.html). For such generators the project is **configured** (with running `cmake`) **once**, but can be **built** for **several** build types after that. Example of such generators is Visual Studio.

For multiconfiguration generators `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is not known at configuration stage. Because of that using `if`-`else` switching doesn't work:

```
# Doesn't work for multi-configuration generators:
#   CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is not defined
#
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    add_compile_definitions("-DDEBUG_LEVEL=2")
elif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    add_compile_definitions("-DDEBUG_LEVEL=0")
endif()
```

But using conditional generator expressions works:

```
add_compile_definitions(
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-DDEBUG_LEVEL=2>
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:-DDEBUG_LEVEL=0>
    )
```

CMake doesn't expand generator expression immediately, when they are declared in the `CMakeLists.txt`. Instead, they remain **packed** until all `CMakeLists.txt` have been be processed. At that time CMake knows all targets created by a project, and properties for that targets, which may contain generator expressions.

Only when create generator-specific build files (e.g. `.sln` file for Visual Studio), CMake expands generator expressions in targets properties: when instantiated for "Debug" build, targets properties are evaluated with `$<CONFIG>` equal to "Debug", when instantiated for "Release" build, targets are evaluated with `$<CONFIG>` equal to "Release", and so on.

Because generator expressions are evaluated only at the end of configuration process, they cannot be printed with `message()` command (More precisely, one may call `message()` for a string, containing a generator expression, but this string will be printed without expansions).

Generally, generator expressions can be used only in those CMake commands and target properties, **which explicitly** documents this usage.